# grep to display folders which contain files which contain a string

Tags: grep

I need to run a grep on my server to search for files which extend a CodeIgniter 1 file, as we are upgrading to CI2. In one folder contains several hundred site-specific folders like such:

```
dev/sitea.com/site/www
dev/siteb.com/site/www
dev/sitec.com/site/www
... and so on
```

How can I grep to find which folders **directly under dev** contain a file (or many files in variable subfolders) which references the string "MY_Output" (php file)

I'm aware of the `-l` flag to list the files, but I'm not sure how to put it with other flags together to say "*show me which websites contain files with this string*"

Is this possible? Thanks!

EDIT: Just to clarify, these site level folders will contain files which extend MY_Output.php, which is a common shared file:

```
class Whatever extends MY_Output
```

Comment: This is not related to apache, ssh or putty (thus I removed the tags).

Comment: I'm using Putty to run these greps. Figured it may be applicable.

Comment: Maybe `bash` could be applicable (as this is most likely the shell you are executing the command in), but the command should not depend on how you connect. (Please do not regard this as an attack, I just wanted to mention why I removed the tags, in case anyone wonders.)

Comment: Perhaps you could include something about what a positive match might look like.  For instance would the file /dev/sitea.com/site/www/file contain the text "MY_Output" within it, or are you looking for "MY_Output" within the path itself?

Comment: As stated in the question, these site folders will contain 0 or more files which extend a common file. I need to find out which sites are extending this common file. MY_Output.php resides out of this directory entirely. The files inside these site level folders, if they extend it, will contain the text "extends MY_Output"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This would be my approach:

```
find dev -type f -print0 | \          # find all files
xargs -0 grep 'extends MY_Output' | \ # search for your string
cut -d/ -f2  | \                      # extract web folder name
sort | uniq                           # eliminate duplicates
```

Note use of the `print0` parameter to `find` and the `-0` (zero) flag to `xargs`, which prevents problems if your filenames have embedded spaces in them.

Comment: Dude. You rock so hard. The first 20 minutes or so were spitting out permission denied errors from tmp files but in the end was a solid list of all the site folders I cared about. Booya +1 and accepted.

Comment: Aww tried to +1 you but I spent all my rep on the bounty haha. Next time ;)

Comment: Excellent solution! For completeness, I would have used `xargs dirname` instead of `cut` and instead of `sort | uniq` just `sort -u`. But there's more than one way to do it :-)

Comment: @Janne `dirname` would have caused at least one extra `stat` call to the file system for each matching file.

Comment: @Alienwebguy, you didn't have to suffer through permission denied errors, if you used a script that can deny them... furthermore, you can reduce search speed many times over by caching results.

Comment: @Guacamole the permission denied errors are a red herring - your script just silently ignores them.  +1 for short circuiting the search on first match, though.

Comment: @Alnitak, silently ignoring errors is a completely valid means to prevent users from suffering through them... and since grep sends them to STDERR, you get much less clutter by ignoring them

Answer (score 4):

I see a lot of needless complexity in the various solutions posted.  Consider the following:

```
grep -r [regex to find] [path to search] | awk -F: '{print $1}' | uniq
```

Comment: You can also use `cut` in place of `awk` for even greater simplicity - I just happen to remember the existence of awk (and its syntax) more readily than cut...

Comment: You could potentially save a lot of time using the `-l` argument to grep so it stops reading through files after it finds a match and moves on. That's easy. Some of the more complex answers here are a whole 'nother level more efficient because they stop scanning a directory after the first match is found.

Comment: +1 for `-l` (an option I consistently neglect).  I wasn't 100% sure if the OP wanted just the directories or the files but it sounded like they would need to edit individual files in each directory, which is why I went with listing each file.  Much time can be saved by bailing if you only need the directory names :)

Answer (score 3):

To find out which websites have a file with MY_output.php inside them follow these steps:

Log into the server using PuTTY.  You should get a command prompt like this:

```
username@hostname:~$
```

Change to your dev directory (not sure where this is on your server, maybe under /var/www ?)

```
cd /var/www/dev
```

Make sure we're in the correct directory

```
ls
```

And we should get something like this:

```
sitea.com
siteb.com
sitec.com
```

Now find every file which contains MY_output.php then shorten list to just the domains:

```
grep -rsl "extends MY_output" * | cut -d/ -f1 | sort | uniq
```

Grep looks for all matching files recursively in all the web directories.  The cut command breaks up your paths and just gives the first directory name (sitea.com, siteb.com, etc.)  The sort and uniq commands just remove duplicate entries so each domain only appears once.

Enjoy!

Comment: This looks promising. The issue though is these site folders won't have that file - MY_Output.php is a common file. The site folders will have files which extend it, hence why I need to find the string MY_Output inside the contents of the files.

Comment: Can I change it to `grep -r "MY_output" * | cut -d/ -f1 | sort | uniq` ?

Comment: Just a follow up, that didn't work either.

Comment: Also tried adding the case-insensitive recursive flag: `grep -iR`

Comment: Can you include a few lines of the files from the files which contain the "MY_output" text along with their path?  Also, try running just the first part of the command: grep -r "MY_output" *  to see if that outputs anything

Comment: AlienWebguy said dev has several hundreds of directories. Using file expansion is not the best approach because the expanded list may be longer than the maximum command line length allowed.

Comment: Ah, I read that as several hundreds of nested directories.  The "*" file expansion will only cause issues if there are several hundreds of SITE directories.  Subdirectories within a site won't be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

use `find` to list all files and then run grep on each one of them:

```
find dev/ | xargs grep -l MY_Output.php
```

**Note**: you must be in the directory containing the dev directory

and if you get errors of unreadable files (permissions etc) then you can append `2>/dev/null`

```
find dev/ | xargs grep -l MY_Output.php 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Putty just responds with `(standard input)`. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: hey, i updated the answer. But honestly i have no idea why you get such error. maybe you should try if `find dev/` gives you all the files in dev directory first. With pipe the `grep` is using this output as its standard input.

Comment: Neither worked unfortunately - the first method returned a bunch of random images, psd's, and permission denied messages, and the 2nd method gave me permission denied

Answer (score 0):

If you log into your server and then cd to the dev folder, this should work:

```
egrep -rl 'class \S+ extends MY_Output' * | awk -v FS="/" '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
```

This will pick up ONLY sites that actually do have classes that extend the MY_Output class, and it will also give you a count of files within that site that you can expect to change. You can also use the cut utility instead of awk:

```
egrep -rl 'class \S+ extends MY_Output' * | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: AlienWebguy said dev has several hundreds of directories. Using file expansion is not the best approach because the expanded list may be longer than the maximum command line length allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, in general terms you want to list which folders contain regular files called **dev/*/*** which themselves contain the string "**MY_Output**" (case sensitive).

More precisely, since the "*" pattern does not match files or directories starting with a ".", you would also want to search for **dev/*/***, **dev/.??*/***, **dev/*/.??*** and **dev/.??*/.??*** . This is a detail that is missing from secretmike's and Brian Showalter's solutions.

Using these four patterns ensures that you process all the files you want and that you don't get extra matches from other (deeper or shallower) files. Normally the list of matching files can be accomplished simply by running:

```
grep -l MY_Output dev/*/* dev/.??*/* dev/*/.??* dev/.??*/.??* 2>/dev/null
```

The **2>/dev/null** part is there to ignore errors such as when you try reading from files without permissions, like you seem to be doing (based on your answer to Imre L's answer). For best results you may want to run this command as root.

Unfortunately there's a limit to command line lengths, and this command may fail if there are too many matching files because the command line would be too long (after expansion). Since you say there's hundreds of directories under **dev**, this approach is not appropriate, although I figure it's worth mentioning here for completeness.

To avoid that problem, the **find** command is better suited:

```
find dev -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f \
    -exec bash -c 'grep -q MY_Output {} && echo {}' \;
```

This is very similar to the answer Imre L gave, although he resorts to **xargs** instead of using the **-exec** switch. But that only gets you the list of matching files, not the list of folders that contain those.

To get what you want we need to filter it a bit further:

```
find dev -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f \
    -exec bash -c 'grep -q MY_Output {} && dirname {}' \; \
        | sort \
        | uniq
```

The **-mindepth** and **-maxdepth** switches ensure we don't get matches from files deeper or shallower in the **dev** tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do something like this:

```
for dir in dev/* ; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ] ; then
        if [ -n "$( find "$dir" -type f \
            -exec grep -q '\<MY_Output\>' {} \; \
            -print | head -1 )" ] ; then
            echo "$dir"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
for dir in dev/* ; do [ -d "$dir" ] && [ -n "$( find "$dir" -type f -exec grep -q '\<MY_Output\>' {} \; -print | head -1 )" ] && echo "$dir" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find (Directory) -iname "(File Pattern>)" -exec zgrep "(String to Find)" {} \;
```

For example:

```
find /opt/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/application/logs/ -iname "SystemOut*" -mtime -7 -exec zgrep "FileNotFoundException" {} \;
```